# The plugin `tflite` uses a deprecated version

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, embedding

The plugin `tflite` uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to see if this plugin supports the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise, consider removing it since a future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs.
If you are plugin author, take a look at the docs for migrating the plugin to the V2 embedding: https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.

Comment: This is self explanatory, tflite uses a deprecated version of Android embedding. You should use [tflite_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/tflite_flutter) instead.

Comment: [tflite_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/tflite_flutter) also giving the same error now